# grails doesn't generate ant build file

Tags: grails, ant

I'm a beginner of Grail. I learned from the quick-start tutorial  that the **grails create-app** will generate a build.xml for Ant.

I execute the command. but couldn't get the build.xml file. Is there missing any steps? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Don said you really don't need it. But if you want the build.xml that used to be automatically created, run

```
grails integrate-with --ant
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/integrate-with.html

Comment: Burt,That is exactly i wanted.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grails may generate a `build.xml` file "under the hood", but there's no reason for you to worry about this, because you don't work with Ant directly when developing with Grails. Instead you use Grails commands (like `create-app`) to create, build, test, deploy, etc. Grails applications.

The `create-app` command creates a new application. To run the application, execute the command `grails run-app` from the root directory of the project.